graphql-constraint-directive in Nestjs
I have a Nestjs GraphQL API & would like to use constraint directive from
graphql-constraint-directive in code-first fashion.
   GraphQLModule.forRootAsync<ApolloDriverConfig>({
          driver: ApolloDriver,
          imports: [DataloaderModule],
          useFactory: (dataloaderService: DataloaderService) => {
            return {
              autoSchemaFile: {
                path: join(process.cwd(), 'schema.graphql'),
              },
              transformSchema: (schema) => constraintDirective()(schema),
              buildSchemaOptions: {
                directives: [
                  new GraphQLDirective({
                    name: 'constraint',
                    locations: [DirectiveLocation.INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION],
                  }),
                ],
              },

then, in a field of an input type;
@Directive('@constraint(minLength: 5)')

directive created in the schema.graphql
directive @constraint on INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION
however, it's not attached to input type in the generated schema.
any suggestion?
